# Where can I find JDK6 source repository?

Tags: java, sun, java-6

On the [JDK6 source page](http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/) the repository link is broken, and the location that is described in readme doesn't exist. I know that there is also OpenJDK repository, but as I understand, it isn't the same.

I know how to download source files, but I'm much more interested in repository, not the jars.

I'm not interested in any other open implementations of JVM.

Comment: you can download the source along w/ the JDK (there is a file called src.zip)

Comment: but he asked, specifically, for the repository, not for the sources...

Comment: @bestsss - jdk6 is more than the (incomplete) collection of java source files that is shipped with the standard jdk

Comment: @Andreas, sure it is; it doesn't even include the native code and so on, or sun code, etc. but it does contain quite a lot of the java standard classes

Comment: @golergka, just downloaded from the link: http://download.java.net/jdk6/6u23/promoted/b05/jdk-6u23-fcs-src-b05-jrl-12_nov_2010.jar the site seems to have some issues, though; and you might try to restart or pause/resume the download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments section of the readme, from the repository, you can see that's been a long time since people complain about the repository not being updated and with access problems.

Try downloading the .jar... as many others have suggested here.

Comment: So, basically, there is no such thing as up-to-date official JDK repository?

Comment: Actually, no, there's no up-to-the-minute official JDK source repository. Now you have to download the .jar or .zip or any other .file archive, and not access a SVN repository.

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/), as an example (and indeed, bestsss is right, there is a source zip in each JDK)

Comment: As I understand, it is not the same as Sun's JDK, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

On [this site](http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/) there is a link to the [source code package](http://www.java.net/download/jdk6/6u23/promoted/b05/jdk-6u23-fcs-src-b05-jrl-12_nov_2010.jar). The link works for me.

Comment: @Tom, that's the published version (i.e. w/o the fix for sun.misc.FloatingDecimal)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I already downloaded that source – I was interested in repository for a more convenient way to be up-to-date with the latest release.

Comment: @golergka The closed JDK repository is, er, closed.

Comment: Tom, the problem is that it isn't said anywhere officially that it's closed, and that creates some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As bestsss said its called src.zip and you can find it in the JDK distribution.

- [This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jdkfiles.html) is the JDK file structure for Windows.
- [This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/linux/jdkfiles.html) is the JDK file structure for Linux.

They should help you find it within the JDK.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I already downloaded that source – I was interested in repository for a more convenient way to be up-to-date with the latest release.

Comment: @golergka You will be up to date with the latest release when you download each new JDK :) There is currently no way to update the JDK or its source via a remote repository like Maven for instance.